# Stuck into Ubuntu 20.04. Dual booting Windows 10 shows blank screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I am stuck in Ubuntu 20.04 because my Windows 10 can't start. When I click on `Windows (UEFI)` to boot windows, it shows a black blank screen and that's it forever. I have to shutdown from there to be able to access grub menu again and Ubuntu when I power on. I have tried upgrading `grub` and many other tricks that I don't remember, and nothing seems to work. I have installed `grub2` and run `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-grub2`, but it didn't seem to help.

Current grub boot menu:

[image]

Comment: @karel, I just tried the answers on that page but nothing too helpful. I had the custom.cfg file exactly as it's there, so I guess I have tried this before. I can see grub menu and the Windows (UEFI) option. Just my Windows comes out blank and can't start.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. And Fast start up must be off, Windows not hibernated nor UEFI Secure Boot on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If UEFI you should be able to directly boot into Windows from UEFI boot menu & change settings. Or you can use your Windows repair/recovery disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... In a terminal:

> sudo grub_mkconfig

Reboot and try win...

Below you will find part of the terminal's "info grub" output... my research reference.

Good luck!!

---

## 6.1 Simple configuration handling

The program 'grub-mkconfig' (*note Invoking grub-mkconfig::) generates
'grub.cfg' files suitable for most cases.  It is suitable for use when
upgrading a distribution, and will discover available kernels and
attempt to generate menu entries for them.

'grub-mkconfig' does have some limitations.  While adding extra
custom menu entries to the end of the list can be done by editing
'/etc/grub.d/40_custom' or creating '/boot/grub/custom.cfg', changing
the order of menu entries or changing their titles may require making
complex changes to shell scripts stored in '/etc/grub.d/'.  This may be
improved in the future.  In the meantime, those who feel that it would
be easier to write 'grub.cfg' directly are encouraged to do so (*note
Booting::, and *note Shell-like scripting::), and to disable any system
provided by their distribution to automatically run 'grub-mkconfig'.

The file '/etc/default/grub' controls the operation of
'grub-mkconfig'.  It is sourced by a shell script, and so must be valid
POSIX shell input; normally, it will just be a sequence of 'KEY=value'
lines, but if the value contains spaces or other special characters then
it must be quoted.  For example:
***********end***********_______